# Guava: how do I build the javadocs from git

Tags: guava

I've pulled down the latest Guava from the public git repository. When I try to create the javadocs, it fails.

I'm using the mvn line: mvn javadoc:javadoc

It fails with a long string of errors, the most obvious one is

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.ClassUseWriter cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.ClassWriterImpl
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.seeTagToString(HtmlDocletWriter.java:1353)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.commentTagsToString(HtmlDocletWriter.java:1443)`

This is straight from git, on a Mac, OS-X 10, 64 bit, 10.6.8 Snow Leopard

While I'd love to get the build to work, I'd be happy with a copy of the javadocs, jar'd or zip'd or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the JavaDocs hosted online http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html

Alternatively, if you need an offline copy, you can check out the javadoc output from git:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries.docs/javadoc/
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a copy that I can have locally for those times when I don't have a live Interenet connection. I tried your git, it fails:
<pre>
git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries.docs/javadoc/ tmp
Cloning into tmp...
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
</pre>

Comment: Sorry, I had the command wrong. Try `git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries.docs/`

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously hitting a bug in your version of javadoc. We've hit ClassCastExceptions like that many, many times, but I haven't seen one in quite a while. Do you have the latest JDK?

Update: [here's some Google results](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&ix=h9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.seeTagToString%28HtmlDocletWriter.java:1353#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.seeTagToString%28HtmlDocletWriter.java:1353%22%20%22com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.commentTagsToString%28HtmlDocletWriter.java:1443%22&oq=%22com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.seeTagToString%28HtmlDocletWriter.java:1353%22%20%22com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.commentTagsToString%28HtmlDocletWriter.java:1443%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...22554.23955.2.24440.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.2.Bg6u_V3fx8c&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d2e01d59c9c5ea6c&ix=h9&biw=1455&bih=848) for this error, if it helps.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-413-10M3623)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-413, mixed mode)

Comment: I am using the same version of java under linux with Maven (both 2.2.1 and 3.0.4) and I'm hitting the same problem. Is there a bug report for this somewhere? This appears to work fine under 1.7.x.

Comment: Yes, Im getting same error for my own project it has been wortking fine on Windows but fails on OSX (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)

Answer (score 0):

We build the public javadoc using the command `mvn clean install site`.

Comment: Did this after a "git pull" and still get errors:

[ERROR] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.ClassUseWriter cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.ClassWriterImpl
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.seeTagToString(HtmlDocletWriter.java:1353)